# How to calculate the cycle time of pipeline

Tags: computer-architecture

I have an 8-stage pipeline (IF,ID,OF1,OF2,OF3,Ex1,Ex2,WB) with respective stage delays as 5ns,4ns,10ns,6ns,8ns,11ns,9ns,13ns respectively. The interstage registers have delay of 1ns.

I think here the cycle time must be 13ns, that of WB stage.And since we don't need register after WB stage, we don't need to add register delay.

Am I correct in my reasoning.

I am new member here and I am preparing for an exam.I got across this question and wanted to ask about it.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Answer (score 0):

No, that's wrong. What about the register output delay in the second-to-last register? And what about the register input setup time?

The minimum clock period of any stage is the sum of:

- clock-to-output delay of the interstage register
- combinatorial delay of the logic
- input-to-clock setup time of the next register (which might be zero, but it needs to be stated)

The overall clock period is the largest period of any individual stage.

Answer (score 0):

Cycle time

= Maximum delay due to any stage + Delay due to its register

= Max { 5ns,4ns,10ns,6ns,8ns,11ns,9ns,13ns} + 1 ns

=14ns